# How do I add the images for associated bundle product in the cart?

Tags: cart, bundled-product

The options data gets called in the `checkout/cart/default.phtml` and I believe it's this function:

```
<?php echo $_formatedOptionValue['value'] ?>
```

.. that produces looped data for each associated item. How can I show the images for the associated bundle items? Let me know if I am not clear.

Answer (score 1):

To display all images for all products selected in the bundle, you'll have to load up the bundle option selections themselves and send to the thumbnail creation helper.

*Warning:* Don't edit theme files directly. Copy to your own theme:

**app/design/frontend/base/default/template/checkout/cart/item/default.phtml:**

Replace this block:

```
<?php if ($_options = $this->getOptionList()):?>
```

With this block:

```
<ul class="bundle-selection">
    <?php foreach($_item->getQuote()->getAllItems()->filterByParent($_item->getId()) as $_selection): ?>
    <li class="bundle-selection">
        <span class="product-thumbnail">
        <img src="<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_selection, 'thumbnail');?>"/></span> <span class="product-name"><?php echo $_selection->getName(); ?></span>
    </li>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</ul>
<?php if ($_options = $this->getOptionList()):?>
```

Comment: This is throwing an error. Also, I'd like to figure out which function in the core actually produces this because I also wan to remove the price and "qty X " in front of the product

Comment: Could you paste the specific error?

Comment: Fatal error: Call to a member function filterByParent() on a non-object in /localwwroot/app/design/frontend/my/theme/template/checkout/cart/item/default.phtml on line 49

Answer (score 0):

Can you please clear your question with some example.

We can change thumbnail of associated image in cart for grouped or configurable products.

```
Go to System >> Configuration >> SALES >> Checkout >> Shopping Cart
```

1) Grouped Product Image
2) Configurable Product Image

Note: Above is useful for only Grouped Or Configurable products.